# Reducing the huge space before the first line of the KOMA letter class

Tags: spacing, koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

How can i reduce the vertical space to the start of the letter?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,firstfoot=false]{scrlttr2} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{%
    ngerman,
    ae,
    times,  %% hier kann man die Schriftart einstellen
    graphicx,
    url}

\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,
fromalign=center,
fromrule=aftername,
backaddress=true,
parskip=half,
enlargefirstpage=true} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{need less space to the very top at the page}      

\let\raggedsignature=\raggedright       

\firsthead{
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{letter}{
    Adress
    }       
 \begin{small}

\opening{opening}

Stuff

\closing{Kind regards}
\end{small}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an appropriate thread title for this site? I mean, trust me, I swear like a drain, I really like it, I think it's very important, but how are you gonna expect people to want to help you if you pose such a combative question? Especially, remember, as this is a site populated by TeX-LaTeX enthusiasts, who really rather like what it does and how it does it

Comment: I'm afraid that making the rest of your life better is not only off-topic, but too broad, primarily opinion-based and unclear.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Don't forget: it's a new user!

Comment: That said, I want to reecho the concerns already raised: do not pose your question combatively. We aren't the cause of your problem.

Comment: The KOMA letter class is designed to place the To: address in a position such that when the letter is folded the address will show through some DIN standard window envelope.  So it's not really designed to be moved much.  But I take it that you want the address to start much higher on the page because you don't care about the window-envelope requirement?

Comment: Just compiled the MWE. Looks fine and matches a standard envelope. Maybe the KOMA letter class is just the wrong one for your needs

Comment: Please, close voters: closing this question as 'Too broad' (the current reason that two people have voted for) is  ridiculous. There is such a thing as pragmatics, and to take the OP's first statement as a literal request is  to be as uncooperative a reader as one can imagine.  The question as it stands is reasonably clear, contains a MWE and is in no sense too broad.  Let's be serious people.

Comment: This closing is unacceptable. [Close voting is not a sport](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6430)

Comment: It really never occurred to me that anybody would take my comment as a proposal to close the question. Besides, the question had been thoroughly pacified by @SeanAllred by the time the close vote was even *initiated*.

Comment: @vierto, as the first person to swing by here and offer you a little essay about your question, I do just want to agree with those above me who've argued that this question shouldn't have been closed - and certainly not closed as too broad. As you originally wrote it, it was a bad question (and I'm sorry to say it was a bad question) in terms of the way it was phrased, but the actual problem you were having - and what you were actually asking for - is on topic and worthy of this site, I just would recommend posting questions a little differently in future. but that's all.

Comment: I hope you get the answers you seek and I hope you stick around, I just wanted to give you a little word of advice about how to operate on this site to get the help you need and to interact fruitfully and happily with others

Comment: Regardless of a question-worthy issue or not, I do believe that the question should also be written (and ideally elaborated) in the body and not in the title alone.

Comment: 14 upvotes for this?

Comment: @SeanAllred Although I didn't vote on this question, I disagree. There is no dichotomy like "good question" vs "bad question". There are questions with a gradation of good/bad. So a score -10 indicates a much worse question than one with a score of -1, just as a score of 1 is much less than a score of 10.

Comment: @Alenanno It's not a matter about being a good/bad question – it's about being a good/bad community. It's about being nice :)

Comment: @SeanAllred That's the point: it's really not about being nice. I mean, there's (usually) nothing personal behind the downvote. It's not a vote on the person, but on the content. Although I can understand that no-one likes getting a downvote. :)

Comment: @Alenanno that's not how it is ever received by a new user. If you want to talk about this further though, open a question on Meta. I can link to the "text building blocks" boilerplate comment collection post so we can change our stance if that's warranted.

Answer (score 31):

The `scrlttr2` class loads the file `DIN.lco` as default. This file contains a parameter set for A4 paper and German window envelopes C4, C5, C6 and C6 long.

But there is another Letter Class Option file that reduces the space above the address: `DINmtext.lco`. Note that such a letter will not fit a C4 or C5 window envelope.

To load the Letter Class Option file `DINmtext.lco` use `DINmtext` as an option for the `scrlttr2` class or insert `\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=12pt,
  firstfoot=false,
]{scrlttr2} 

\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}% <- loads DINmtext.lco

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}% <- instead package ngerman
\usepackage{%
    times,
    graphicx,
    url}

\KOMAoptions{
  fromalign=center,
  fromrule=aftername,
  backaddress=true,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=true,
} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{need less space to the very top at the page}      

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}% <-redefining \raggedsignature    

\setkomavar{firsthead}{ % <- the command \firsthead is outdated, use \setkomavar{firsthead}{...} instead
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{
      Adress
      }       
  \small% <- it is a switch but not an environment
  \opening{opening}
  Stuff
  \closing{Kind regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But may be you want to top align the address in the address field. Then add  `addrfield=topaligned` to your KOMA Option list:

```
\KOMAoptions{
  fromalign=center,
  fromrule=aftername,
  backaddress=true,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=true,
  addrfield=topaligned %< added
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You.
I posted my question here because i get many help in past when google guided me to here. Thats just the point. So thank You and have a nice day!

Comment: @viertro: Instead of writing a `thank you` comment only, consider to accept `esdd` solution and thereby appreciating her work and efforts to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @esdd's answer, a quick fix for decreasing vertical spacing between Recipient and Subject can be to make use of the following:

```tex
\makeatletter
\@setplength{refvpos}{6.5cm}
\makeatother
```

Add it after your document starts.